# Electron-Updater detects update, but doesn't download it

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

**The idea:**

`electron-updater` is supposed to update my `electron` software automatically when a new version is released.

**The problem:**
`electron-updater` detects the new version, but does not download and install it.
I use `electron-updater@4.3.8` and build my app with `electron-builder@8.17.0`. 
Switching to older versions unfortunately did not help either.

**Update**:

Electron now throws the error `autoUpdater.autoDownload is not a function`.

**Code snippets**

Main.js:

```
    // autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify() is called in "mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', ...)

    // ------ AutoUpdater ------ //
    autoUpdater.logger = log;
    autoUpdater.logger.transports.file.level = 'info';

    const sendStatusToWindow = (text) => {
      log.info(text);
      if (mainWindow) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('update', text)
      }
    }

    autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
      sendStatusToWindow('Checking for update...')
    })

    autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
      sendStatusToWindow('Update available.')
      autoUpdater.autoDownload()
    })

    autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
      sendStatusToWindow('Update not available.')
    })

    autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
      log.error(`Update-Error: ${err.toString()}`)
      mainWindow.webContents.send('message', `Error in auto-updater: ${err.toString()}`)
    })

    autoUpdater.on('download-progress', progressObj => {
      sendStatusToWindow(
        `Download speed: ${progressObj.bytesPerSecond} - Downloaded ${progressObj.percent}% (${progressObj.transferred} + '/' + ${progressObj.total} + )`
      )
    })

    autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', () => {
      sendStatusToWindow('Update downloaded; will install now')
      autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
    })
```

Package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "iac_2",
      "productName": "IAC 2.0",
      "version": "0.8.3-alpha",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/JueK3y/Instagram-automated-commenting",
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/JueK3y/Instagram-automated-commenting"
      },
      "main": "main.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "electron-builder"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^15.5.7"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "electron-log": "^4.4.8",
        "electron-updater": "^4.3.8",
        "electron-window-state": "^5.0.3",
        "is-online": "^9.0.1",
        "keytar": "^7.9.0",
        "network-speed": "^2.1.1",
        "node-notifier": "^10.0.1",
        "puppeteer": "^16.0.0",
        "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.4",
        "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.0"
      },
      "build": {
        "appId": "jue3ky.iac_2.app",
        "productName": "IAC 2.0",
        "copyright": "Copyright © 2022 by JueK3y",
        "win": {
          "target": "nsis",
          "icon": "icon.ico",
          "publish": {
            "provider": "github"
          }
        },
        "asar": true,
        "asarUnpack": "node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/**/*"
      }
    }
```

Full code is here: https://github.com/JueK3y/Instagram-automated-commenting/tree/main/public

Comment: When you say that the download fails, are you getting any information on the error whatsoever? If yes, please [edit] your question and include the error message. Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no error. I get a message that a new version was found and then nothing happens.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Tried a bit and now I get the error: "autoUpdater.autoDownload is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `autoUpdater.autoDownload()` fixed the `autoUpdater.autoDownload is not a function` error.


The other error, that the update is not downloaded, was related to `GitHub` for me. There the `.exe` file was named differently than the `.exe.blockmap` file, which is why electron-updater returned a `404` error.